# Tag Cleanup For Graduation

Tags: discussion, tags

We all know the site is graduating soon and one nice thing to do before we are fully graduated is to clean up the tags on the main site. We have almost 300 tags and tags are very important to organizing questions asked and making sure people who are interested in a topic can find questions and answers easily.

## We should all make sure that:

- Duplicate tags are made [synonyms](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).
- Useless tags are removed.
- Tag Wikis are not missing (Good chance for users under 1k rep to get a little rep).
- Tags are applied where they need to be applied.

Post below if you think any tags that need cleaning (dupes, mistakes, unneeded, blacklisting etc) and we'll decide as a community what to do.

---

Current pending [synonyms](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms):

- [key](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key) <- [key-signatures](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-signatures)
- [maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) <- [instrument-care](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-care)
- [rock-n-roll](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-n-roll) <- [rock](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock)

Removed Tags:

- [alternatives](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternatives)
- [diminished](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diminished)

Comment: related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/813/should-we-make-the-tag-instrument-care-a-synonym-of-maintenance

Comment: also related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/949/104

Comment: Remember, undoing tag synonyms/merges is more difficult than doing them, so if we spend a wee bit of time here to agree and fully check each one, it will be quick and easy to then carry out the updates confident they are correct.

Comment: I don't think [tag:maintenance] and [tag:instrument-care] should be synonyms either - but I've expressed that in the related thread above.

Answer (score 12):

I believe the [learning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) <- [pedagogy](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) synonym request should be declined, and instead:

[teaching](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) <- [pedagogy](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy)

Reference: [oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedagogy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedagogy)

Comment: `status-completed`

Answer (score 10):

The tag [alternatives](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternatives) should be removed because it doesn't really give any information about what the question is about. Of the 3 questions it is tagged in, 1 is closed and the other two are about completely different topics. One is about alternate solfege and is about if a cajon can be an alternate drum set.

Comment: `status-completed`

Answer (score 10):

On the [pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedals) issue that Charles raised, I propose that [pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedals) as a tag itself is scrapped.

Lots of the questions should be retagged [effects-pedal](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects-pedal).

Those questions referring to piano or harp pedals, I think the [pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedals) tag could just be removed - I'm not sure it's possible to be an expert only in playing the piano with a pedal, and not [piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piano) in general.

[guitar-effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-effects) and [effects-pedal](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects-pedal) should be kept separate - effects pedals are not only used for guitars (I'm thinking loopers), and it's possible to also create guitar effects without the use of a pedal. (I believe, not my area!)

Comment: Sounds good to me. Also there are guitar effects that aren't pedals, so your solution makes sense.

Comment: There is another concept with pedal in the name: pedal point. Don't think there's many questions about that, and agree on "effects-pedal".

Comment: Hmm...can you be an expert in pedal notes? (Which according to google is another name for 'pedal point'!)

Comment: For guitar-effects, I'm not seeing many in guitar-specific non-electronic effects, such as harp harmonics, above-the-nut bends, pinch harmonics and the like. If I asked about dive-bombing with a Floyd Rose or string bending to emulate a pedal steel, those would be guitar effects, but any instrument with an electronic output can be plugged into a delay or overdrive pedal. The other world fit under guitar-technique or something

Comment: @VarLogRant - I'm confused, are you suggesting that [tag:guitar-effects] should also be merged into something? There doesn't currently seem to be a guitar-technique tag - are you suggesting there's a better current tag these should be merged into?

Comment: @Chris - Sorry about the confusion. I think that everything I see in the [guitar-effects](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-effects) tag should be tagged with [effects-pedal](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects-pedal) instead. I gave examples of things that could be "guitar effects", and think they should have another tag instead. Maybe "guitar", "electric guitar" or "acoustic guitar".

Comment: It is true that there's also onboard effects and rackmount effects, but I don't think breaking that out of effects-pedal is worth it.

Comment: @VarLogRant hmm, ok, not my area of expertise at all, I'll admit!

Comment: @VarLogRant I'd propose merging `effects-pedal` into `guitar-effects` since the latter more general, I don't see an advantage to going the other way.  Chris, I think your argument about piano pedalling being a subset of piano is not a good reason to remove `pedals`, since the same logic could be applied to removing `effects-pedal`/`guitar-effects`.  A rename would be better.

Comment: @Matthew - `Effects-pedals` (loopers) can be used for many instruments, not just guitars - I wouldn't agree with that merge.

Comment: @Matt: I stand by my original post on `pedals`. Piano pedals work in a simple way and make a limited number of changes to the sound - I don't believe there's enough questions to justify a separate `piano-pedals` tag. `guitar` attracts way more questions, and there are way more possibilities under the 'guitar-effects' banner, and thus more questions which could be asked. I would also imagine that `guitar-effects` questions are a subset some guitarists may wish to only follow, and others may wish to filter out (classical players?) - whereas piano pedals are a more staple part of playing piano.

Comment: I think my point is: piano's come with pedals as standard. Guitar-pedals are an added extra the player may or may not use

Comment: Questions about piano pedal usage are helpful for newbies. I’d recommend keeping that usage but renaming it to something like `keyboard-pedals`. As for `guitar-effects` and `effects-pedal`, while I can see a difference between the two, there is also a vast overlap, and in practice I always end up tagging with both, or choosing one arbitrarily, when I want to ask a question about effects.

Answer (score 7):

[key](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key) <- [key-signatures](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-signatures) should be a synonymy because they both are typically used to talk about keys and are typically used interchangeably. Even if the questions that talk specifically about the key signature the key signature is part of the key.

Comment: I'm not totally agreed with this.  For those that want to learn specifically about key signatures, the tag is a useful category.

Comment: @MatthewRead I would tend to agree, but as the current tagging stands they are used interchangeably. If you check questions tagged [tag:key-signatures] most of them are about keys themselves not the key signature.

Comment: Hmmm - just re-reading this. Should we maybe keep these 2 tags, but edit them so they are used correctly?

Comment: @DrMayhem That's a possibility. I think the trickier thing would be getting people to understand when you should use one or the other (or both). I just did a quick check and there are at least 20 questions that  need to be retagged to either be switched to the other one or add the other one.

Answer (score 6):

I just found [instrument-maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-maintenance) -- should be merged with [maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance).

Answer (score 4):

With the current effects and pedal tags, it’s extremely difficult to choose a reasonable set of tags for guitar effects pedals. I usually end up choosing arbitrarily between [guitar-effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-effects) and [effects-pedal](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects-pedal), and clearly many other people simply choose [pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedals). That’s a mess – there is so much overlap between these things that we should not have 3+ separate tags for them.

The [pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedals) tag should be split into its main uses:

- [guitar-effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-effects) for pedals related to guitar effects
- [looper-pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looper-pedals) for sampling and looping pedals
- [keyboard-pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-pedals) for piano and organ pedals
- [pedal-points](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedal-points) for bass note pedal points

We should make [effects-pedal](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects-pedal) a synonym of [guitar-effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-effects) and then retag anything that is not actually about guitar effects, like [looper-pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looper-pedals). Once the [pedals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedals) tag has all non-guitar questions removed from it, we can also make that a synonym of the most common “pedal” type questions, probably [guitar-effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-effects).

Comment: Since this fills-out the details of Chris's popular answer, I went ahead edited the tag wiki to read "Do not use" with your list of alternatives. And have started re-tagging questions when I have the energy.

Comment: What about [tag:organ-pedals]? It is significantly different from [tag:keyboard-pedals].

Comment: True, they are only superficially similar. Depends on whether we actually have any questions about them that people care enough about to separate piano and organ pedals. (Also note that guitar pedals are largely more similar in form than actual musical function, but we keep them together.)

Comment: So, the other day I asked a question about putting Velcro on guitar pedals, where I actually wanted a *pedals* tag to indicate that I'm talking about the physical hardware and not its function. Not sure whether it actually changes my answer here but it's something to think about.

Comment: I don't think we should have a tag for pedal-points as we don't have any tags in general for non-harmonic tones.

Comment: @Dom That’s just my suggested name if there are any posts actually tagged for that reason. We needn’t create it if there is no use for it.

Answer (score 3):

The [diminished](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diminished) tag should be removed for a few reasons.

First of all it is unclear what the subject is as there are diminished chord, intervals, scales, and diminished could even apply to rhythms (technically a diminution, but the same root word). Another tag would be needed to make it clear what you were talking about and then the diminished tag would be unnecessary because it is a subset of that topic.

Secondly, we do not have [major](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/major) and [minor](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minor) tags and they are the more prevalent scales, chords, intervals, ect in music and I consider the fact that we don't have or need those tags that we don't need a diminished tag.

Comment: `status-completed`

Answer (score 3):

Found [simple-time-signatures](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simple-time-signatures) and [compound-time-signatures](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compound-time-signatures) -- these are overkill given the existing [time-signatures](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-signatures).

Comment: 0 questions tagged for each, so they should be safe to remove...

Answer (score 2):

[overtones](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overtones) should be dropped: only two questions, one about didgeridoo (an overtone instrument) and one about the difference between harmonics and overtones.
Since [harmonics](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmonics) already exists for (essentially) all questions related to overtones, we can safely drop it.

Comment: Perhaps make overtones a synonym of harmonics?

Answer (score 0):

The [tetrachords](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetrachords) tag should be removed as any question that talks about tetrachords would be talking about scales and how they are made which we already have a tag for.

Comment: I don't disagree, but as words go, that one's pretty double-plus good.